# Kinesis Java consumer - keepalive/heartbeat?

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis

Ive written a Java service that consumes from a **Kinesis** topic. The service starts / runs well and consumes happily as long as the data doesn't get too infrequent. If there is a gap of > 60-90 minutes it stops consuming. No errors are issued but subsequent data queues up in Kinesis and sits until the service is restarted.

Does Kinesis have some sort of heartbeat or keepalive message that needs to send during these quiet periods?

I looked through the configuration (**KinesisClientLibConfiguration**) and didn't see anything obvious. Hopefully this won't entail cycling the connection on an hourly basis.

---

### Edit:

```
KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration = 
    new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(config.getString("appname"),
        config.getString("kinesis/stream_name"),
        kinesisCredentialsProvider, localProvider, 
        localProvider, workerId);

kinesisClientLibConfiguration.withInitialPositionInStream(
      InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON);
```

---

### Edit:

I managed to find some error output - lots of these:

> com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask call
>   SEVERE: ShardId shardId-000000000000: Caught exception: 
>   com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredTokenException; Request ID: cdb95cb6-23bb-0067-9c7b-1ad1125d7b7e)

These messages start precisely 60 minutes after the app starts. Found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-token-expired/) reference saying to 'refresh 5 minutes before expiration'. Given that I have two kinds of credentials in this call (one for kinesis and one for dynamodb/cloud watch) I'll try a timer to `.refresh()`.

Comment: you might want to show your `KinesisClientLibConfiguration` code. I am guessing your consumer config is for that Shard is reaching `END_OF_SHARD`? Can you check your consumerTable in dynamodb too?

Answer (score 0):

(here's what worked)

Note: this involves two **Credentials** sources - a local and a remote. The local ones are for **DynamoDB** and **CloudWatch**. The remote is for **Kinesis**.

```
AWSCredentialsProvider localProvider = new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("credentials");

STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider stsRoleCredentials = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(
  config.getString("kinesis/arn"), config.getString("kinesis/role_session_name"))
  .withExternalId(config.getString("kinesis/external_id")).build();

KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration = new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(
  config.getString("appname"),
  config.getString("kinesis/stream_name"),
  stsRoleCredentials, localProvider, localProvider, workerId);
```

If you use a **CredentialsProvider** it will do the token refresh for you. After some exploration I found that the `.refresh()` calls I was making were to empty functions.